# ios map- Creating view on ios map using latitude and longtitude points

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios4, google-maps-api-3, ios6

I have locating places on ios map using pin point and lines. **Now how create a view on that locating place.** [image]

`In this above picture is i located the places using pin and lines. now i want to create a view inside the locating places.` how can i do this. please some body help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have annotation on screen . The annotation are Latitude and lagnitude values  .

```
    NSArray *data = [root objectForKey:@"data"];
    for (NSArray *row in data) {
    NSNumber * latitude = [[row objectAtIndex:22]objectAtIndex:1];
    NSNumber * longitude = [[row objectAtIndex:22]objectAtIndex:2];
    NSString * crimeDescription = [row objectAtIndex:18];
    NSString * address = [row objectAtIndex:14];

    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
    coordinate.latitude = latitude.doubleValue;
    coordinate.longitude = longitude.doubleValue;
    MyLocation *annotation = [[MyLocation alloc] initWithName:crimeDescription address:address coordinate:coordinate] ;
    [_mapView addAnnotation:annotation];
}
```

It can be help you 
1. http://www.raywenderlich.com/21365/introduction-to-mapkit-in-ios-6-tutorial

. http://spitzkoff.com/craig/?p=1082